# How to store data to use throughout the application in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I have an application. In that, I want to share data throughout the application.

1) I thought of using `global`. But it is not best practice as we can access/modify that data from anywhere.

2) I can use `exports` and `require` to `export` and `import` data. But in the exported file, I am getting data only after `pageLoaded`. So, I can't export data.

So, help me is there any NativeScript way to do this.

**Note:** The file from which I want to share data is loaded initially when the app launches initially. Already loaded, so can I access the ViewModel data?

Thank you...

Comment: if you want it persistent between launches, you can use the app settings. if you just want to store it while the app is running, you should use an injectable class to store the data which can then be accessed throughout your app

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, I  just want to store it while the app is running. Can you explain more about `injectable class`.

Comment: sure, ill post as an answer

Comment: Thank you. I am using NativeScript core. Not angular version.

Comment: In which case im not sure then, i dont use vanilla

Comment: You mean you do it using `angular`. But, I am using NativeScript core with VanillaJS.

Comment: yes, i dont use vanilla nativescript

Comment: @mast3rd3mon is it possible to share data between two nativescript application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nativescript's application settings. Save the data as a setting in one file, and get the setting in some other file. See https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application-settings for more details.